# Can't Produce "< Back" on Swift Navigation bar Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Let me first begin by saying I am doing all of my coding programmatically. My problem is that I can't produce the classic iOS "<back" in my navigation bar. I suspect this is because I'm not using story boards?

This is the function I am using to create the navigation bar:

```
// Makes a navigation Bar
func makeNavigationBar(navigationBar: UINavigationBar, barTitle: String, forwardButton: Bool, backButton: Bool, page: UIViewController){
  // Create a navigation item with a title
  let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
  navigationItem.title = barTitle

  // Create left navigation item
  if(backButton){
    let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: page, action: "backClicked:")
    // Create two buttons for the navigation item
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
  }
  if(forwardButton){
    let rightButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: page, action: "nextClickedClicked:")
    // Create two buttons for the navigation item
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
  }
  // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
  navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
  //Adds the bar to the view
  page.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
}
```

This is the call I am making to that function:

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, height/12)) 
creationFunctions.makeNavigationBar(navigationBar, barTitle: "", forwardButton: false, backButton: true, page: self)
```

Here is the "backClicked" function:

```
func backClicked (sender: UIBarButtonItem!){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you should set the back value on the controller that is "pushing" , something like `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: page, action: "backClicked:")` You could add this code on your perform segue with identifier.

Comment: @Lucho can I still do that if I'm not doing preform segue with identifier? I'm only doing present and dismiss

Comment: Try adding it on viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Lucho that doesn't seem to work. DO you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You do not need a storyboard to get the back button. It is built right into the UINavigationController. If you don't mess with it, it should "just work".

Comment: @james it definitely isn't. Is there a special way I have to implement the UINavigationController? Or the present and dismiss funcitons?

Comment: You want to be using https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated: to push, and pop (the next function on the page) to push. When I use this design, everything works out without any effort. That said, I did not implement a custom UINavigationBar; I just used the one that came with the UINavigationController.

Comment: @James I switched to using the UINavigationController and now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi here it is code that creates  custom back button and add it navigationController. I have these methods in my ViewController class.

```
func addBackButton() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "BackImage")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "backClicked:")
}

func backClicked (sender: UIBarButtonItem!){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil);
}
```

Hope it help you

Comment: I'm using present and dismiss cause they aren't in a stack. Can I still use push and pop with that?

Comment: Of course, when they aren't in a stack you can't use pop, my mistake. Check out edited code.

Comment: Why do I need a back image? Shouldn't the default back arrow be loaded in?

Comment: This code is from my project where I create the custom button with my own image, but I made a quick test with 
`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title : "title", style: .Plain, target : self, action :"popBack")` 
and I see only "title" text without the arrow.

Comment: Right, I'm looking for the default apple "<" arrow. I think using navigation controllers then pushing and popping might work?